# Elasticsearch not sorting properly

Tags: json, sorting, elasticsearch

I have a problem with an elasticsearch query. I am running a filtered term query, sorting it by date and outputting only the 100 latest results. I have some indices from 2014 with quite a bit of data in them, which I'm not really interested in. Here's what bothers me: when I do the search, I keep getting results from October 2014, even though I know there are more resent results. I checked the mapping for the indices, and all the timestamp fields are correctly typed as `dateOptionalTime`.

Is the sorting broken or am I querying wrong?
The full query can be seen here:

```
GET _search
{
  "sort": [
  {
    "@timestamp": {
      "order": "desc",
      "ignore_unmapped": "true"
    }
  }
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [{
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "host": "cs-ccr-dmnp2"
              }
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 100,
    "fields": [
      "@timestamp",
      "host"
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Investigate this a bit more! Look for specific documents that you know FOR SURE that they should be in the results.

Comment: I did already :-) And they are all in the result. It's just not sorted...

Comment: Ok :-). Can you post more details about this not-sorting problem? Post the documents that you think it should be sorted and are not.